# I need help on this backtesting pinescript

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

The below consist of the pinescript which I have written.

I am new to pinescript and would like to seek help regarding the pinescript that I have been working on. Basically, the issue is in the "EntryCondition" where the "bullishEC" and "MA Conditions" do not work concurrently. However, they work individually if I remove either the BullishEC condition or the MA Conditions. Please advise, any input/help would be greatly appreciated!

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © thrilledBook49599

//@version=5
strategy('RSI2 Strategy', overlay=true)

// Get price of SPX500USD,1H,CLOSE
spx500usd_price = request.security('spx500usd', '60', close)

// Creating EMA Indicator
spx500usd_ema10 = ta.ema(spx500usd_price, 10)
spx500usd_ema200 = ta.ema(spx500usd_price, 200)

//Create an RSI Indicator
r = ta.rsi(close, 2)

//Create Engulfing Candle
BullishEC = open[1] > close[1] and close > open and close >= open[1] and close[1] >= open and close - open > open[1] - close[1]
BearishEC = close[1] > open[1] and open > close and open >= close[1] and open[1] >= close and open - close > close[1] - open[1]

//Create Entry Conditions Variable
longCondition = (close > spx500usd_ema200 and close < spx500usd_ema10) and r<10 and BullishEC
closelongCondition = r > 90
shortCondition = (close > spx500usd_ema200 and close < spx500usd_ema10) and r<10 and BullishEC
closeshortCondition = r < 10

strategy.entry('long', strategy.long, when=longCondition)
strategy.close('long', when=closelongCondition)

strategy.entry('short', strategy.short, when=shortCondition)
strategy.close('short', when=closeshortCondition)

plot(spx500usd_ema10)
plot(spx500usd_ema200)
plotshape(BearishEC, title='Bearish Engulfing', color= color.red, style=shape.arrowdown, text='Bearish\nEngulfing')
plotshape(BullishEC, title='Bullish Engulfing', location=location.belowbar, color=color.green, style=shape.arrowup, text='Bullish\nEngulfling')
```

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you 2 reasons.

#1

TradingView is not supporting hedge trade backtesting. Which means you cannot LONG and SHORT together.

#2

`strategy.entry` allows you to entry a single entry, unless you set [pyramiding](https://kodify.net/tradingview/strategy-settings/strategy-pyramiding/) option.

USE `strategy.order` instead. It allows you to make multiple orders.

I also suggest you to check how many position you have.
Because It will keep ordering limitlessly.

`strategy.opentrades` gives you number of position.

example)

```
    if strategy.opentrades < 5
       strategy.order(conditions)
```

Even if you use [strategy.order], you cannnot hedge BTW.

Is it helpful? I wish you luck!